# Unable to run ./cim.sh for ATG 10.1.2 using Weblogic App Server

Tags: atg

Hi Everyone,
                    I have installed ATG 10.1.2 , along with CRS , Search , CSC  on my Linux machine. I'm using weblogic as my application server. However, when i try to run ./cim.sh , I get an error which is as follows

It says that its unable to find the class weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClassFinder .

I have set my environment variables as follows :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/install/mediaStore/jdk1.6.0_41
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:/home/install/software/ant/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin:/home/install/Oracle11gR2/install/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:$PATH
export ANT_HOME=/home/install/software/ant/apache-ant-1.8.2
export PATH=$PATH:ANT_HOME/bin
export DYNAMO_ROOT=/home/install/mediaStore/ATG/ATG10.1.2
export DYNAMO_HOME=$DYNAMO_ROOT/home
export ATGJRE=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
export CLASSPATH=/home/install/Oracle11gR2/install/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar:$CLASSPATH
export WEBLOGIC_HOME=/home/install/mediaStore/Weblogic
export WEBLOGIC_SERVER=$WEBLOGIC_HOME/wlserver_12.1
```

[install@JJPLRHEL01 bin]$ ./cim.sh
The following installed ATG components are being used to launch:
  ATGPlatform version 10.1.2 installed at /home/install/mediaStore/ATG/ATG10.1.2

```
Error      Thu Feb 28 15:21:35 IST 2013    1362045095625   /       **atg.nucleus.NucleusResources->cantResolveComponent : Unable to resolve component /atg/dynamo/service/validation/JavaxValidatorFactory**        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/utils/classloaders/ClassFinder
Error      Thu Feb 28 15:21:35 IST 2013    1362045095625   /               at javax.validation.Validation.byProvider(Validation.java:166)
Error      Thu Feb 28 15:21:35 IST 2013    1362045095625   /       ***Caused by :java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.utils.classloaders.ClassFinder***
Error      Thu Feb 28 15:21:35 IST 2013    1362045095625   /               at
```

Any help or views or guidance would be highly appreciated .

Thanks ,
Aazim

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my classpath

/home/install/mediaStore/Weblogic/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/wls-api.jar

Also, currently ATG 10.1.2 does not support Weblogic 12.1. So, you won't be able to configure CRS with it.